# What is the (Ratio estimator for the) covariance of two weighted means?

Tags: weighted-mean, survey-sampling, survey-weights, weighted-sampling, weighted-variance

In a previous question I've asked [How to estimate the (approximate) variance of the weighted mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525741/how-to-estimate-the-approximate-variance-of-the-weighted-mean), specifically, how to prove the following formula:

$$
\widehat{\sigma_{\bar{y}_w}^2} = \frac{1}{(\sum{w_i} )^2}  \sum w_i^2(y_i - \bar{y}_w)^2
$$

For some weighted mean:

$$\overline {y_w} = \frac{\sum{w_i y_i}}{\sum{w_i}}$$

Let's assume we have another set of weights ($v_i$), that are applied to the same set of observations. i.e.:

$$\overline {y_v} = \frac{\sum{v_i y_i}}{\sum{v_i}}$$

My question is what is the covariance of these two weighted means, from a survey statistics perspective (assuming that the selection probability of each observation is independent of other selection probabilities).

Specifically, is it correct to say that the (estimated) covariance will be:

$$cov({\bar{y}_w, \bar{y}_v}) = \widehat{\sigma_{\bar{y}_w, \bar{y}_v}} = \frac{1}{\sum{w_i} \sum{v_i}}  \sum (w_i v_i(y_i - \bar{y}_w)(y_i - \bar{y}_v))$$

If it is true, could someone please help with the proof? (or alternatively, a reference?)

Comment: [Apply the standard covariance formula to this linear combination.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38721) Or are you perhaps trying to compute some kind of *empirical covariance?*  Or maybe estimate a covariance?

Comment: Thanks @whuber
I'm talking about estimation of the quantity.
If I were to assume that we have a random variable X and Y, and assume the realizations are i.i.d, then doing so would be very easy. The problem is that in the survey statistics framework X and Y are constants, and the randomization appears in a latent variable I_i and I_j which indicate if each observations of X and Y (from the population) appear. In that context, the formula of the var I reference comes from - and I'm wondering about it's relation to the estimation of cov.

Comment: I am familiar with and understand that survey statistics formulation but still have no idea what your question is about!  If, perhaps, you could rephrase it in those specific terms, indicating clearly what quantities are random variables, what quantities are constants, and what exactly you mean by "covariance," then your question would be decipherable -- and likely readily answerable.

Comment: Where does the second set of weights come from? That matters for the variance and covariance.